# Enabling Territory Reports in Territory Management 2.0

Tags: reporting, record-type, territory-management, territory

We have enabled Territory Management 2.0 in our Salesforce org. However, we cannot find the Territory Reports as described here:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_territory.htm&language=en_US

How do we add/enable these reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, Salesforce does not include standard, out of the box Territory reports with Territory Management 2.0. They only include Territory reports for the original territory management feature.

One must custom [build their own Territory Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tm2_create_custom_report_types.htm&language=en_US) using Salesforce reporting features.

Answer (score 0):

You build Territory Management 2.0 custom reports from custom report types. See here for info on creating the report types and which reports you can build from those types. Thanks.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tm2_create_custom_report_types.htm&language=en_US